# my c program for factorial is not giving any value in the output box though it shows no errors

Tags: c, codeblocks

**c program**

*my c program for factorial is not giving any value in the output box though it shows no errors*

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {
        int a,n,t=1;
        printf("enter the number\n");
        scanf("%d",a);
        for(n=1;n<=a;n++)
        {
            t*=n;
        }
        printf("the factorial is %d",t);
    }
```

[image: the image]

Comment: `scanf("%d",&a);` Also get an up-to-date C book. Looks like you are using K&R or some other *old* book.

Comment: wow, that was quick, thanks. that was a stupid error. I was not referring to any book, just freewheeling.

Comment: A free-wheeler should know that the correct definition is `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass address of variable a like this..
`scanf("%d", &a);`